# Rails controller doesn't recognize render with return statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `respond_to do |format|` type of explicit structure to render my responses. What works is this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if something
    format.json { render json: something, status: :ok }
  else
    format.json { render json: something_else, status: :ok }
  end
end
```

However, when I tried to do this (for no particular reason, just for learning).

```
respond_to do |format|
  if something
    format.json { render json: something, status: :ok }
    return
  end
  format.json { render json: something_else, status: :ok }
end
```

It gives me "missing template" error. I tried all kinds of variants and for some reason it just ignores what I rendered before the return statement. I really don't understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It because of the structure of your code. You would need to do something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if something
    format.json { render json: something, status: :ok and return }
  end
  format.json { render json: something_else, status: :ok }
end
```

The code to handle the `json` format is contained in the brackets {}, so putting `return` after it doesn't make sense. To illustrate, you could have this structure:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if something
    format.json { render json: something, status: :ok and return}
    format.html { render "new" and return }
  end
  format.json { render json: something_else, status: :ok }
  format.html { render "edit" }
end
```

And it would automatically respond to what format the request is in (and if it is defined).

Comment: for some weird reason, even if I do it like the first one you illustrated, it will executes the code after `end`...